# React Query: rerun onSuccess method of a cached query

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-query

### What I have

I am getting the user's location (latitude/longitude) which I use to call a google [geocode API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse), unless the user's coords change, the request is not running again, since the query it uses the user's coords as queryKey array dependecy.

### The problem

the problem is that I'm running some operations in the `onSuccess` query method, this method is only run when any of the queryKey dependencies change, and I mentioned this not happen.

**How to run the `onSuccess` method whether the queryKey dependencies change or not?**

### Reference code

```js
export const useGoogleReverseGeocoding = (coords) => {
  const url = 'someUrl';
  const request = createClient(); // axios abstraction

  return useQuery({
    queryKey: ['google-geocode', coords],
    queryFn: request,
    enabled: !!coords,
    onSuccess: (data) => {
      const searchTerm = removeGlobalCodeText(data?.plus_code?.compound_code);
      // set searchterm in a global store. This searchterm change with 
      // different user actions, so if the user re-share his location
      // I need to run onSuccess transformation again.
      setSearchTerm(searchTerm); 
    },
  });
};
```

Comment: If you want to rerun the use Query, it returns refetch and I think coords passed to the hook is a object, you can destructure it so prevent extra rerenders

Comment: Here's a method ... I don't think is recommended as it'll run the query again (highly likely)... is when yu provide coords to useGeocoding function, provide it as useGeocoding({ ...coords })

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on the use of the spread operator to avoid re renders or run new query execution. On the other hand I don't want the quiery to rerun only the onsuccess code. Do you consider better to use an effect in which you validate if the query returns data and executes the onsuccess code there ? The idea is take adavnatage of react query cache but run the onsuccess code if the react query hook has data

Comment: You'll need to elaborate more.. Why would you need to 're-run' your operation on the data if the data hasn't changed? What is your onSuccess handler doing? I suspect that you're going about this the wrong way but I don't understand enough about the use case to advise you.

Comment: what I do is transform the data coming from google places and use it to display the name of the user's current location in a human-readable way. I mean if the user shared his location like `{coords: lat: 33.748997, lng: -84.387985}` I will show `Atlanta`, this is run in the onSuccess method but this is executed only once, if the query data doesnt change, the transformation is not done again, I must make clear that this data changes with some user actions so if the user shares his location again the transformation must be re-run. update the reference code

Comment: `onSuccess` can't be fired without the query itself firing again. You mention that certain user actions should also trigger this query to fire. Have you considered [invalidating the query](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/guides/query-invalidation) upon these actions?

Comment: where should I invalidate it? inside the hook that wraps react query useQuery? @ivanatias

Comment: I posted an answer to explain this, please check.

Answer (score 1):

As I was explaining in my comment, `onSuccess` can't be fired without the query itself firing again. Since certain user actions should trigger the transformations on `onSuccess`, you have a couple of ways to go about this, one of them would be to move these transformations on a `useEffect` hook and add some user action related flag on the dependencies array. The other proposed solution would be to [invalidate the query](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/guides/query-invalidation) upon these user actions, so it will be refetched and the transformations on `onSuccess` will execute.

You can achieve this using [useQueryClient](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/reference/useQueryClient) hook which returns the current `QueryClient` instance. You can invalidate the query from anywhere as long as the component is wrapped by `QueryClientProvider`. For this example and for convenience, I will include this hook on `useGoogleReverseGeocoding` custom hook.

**Example:**

**Custom hook:**

```
export const useGoogleReverseGeocoding = (coords) => {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient()
  const url = 'someUrl';
  const request = createClient(); // axios abstraction

  const geocodingData = useQuery({
    queryKey: ['google-geocode', coords],
    queryFn: request,
    enabled: !!coords,
    onSuccess: (data) => {
      const searchTerm = removeGlobalCodeText(data?.plus_code?.compound_code);
      // set searchterm in a global store. This searchterm change with 
      // different user actions, so if the user re-share his location
      // I need to run onSuccess transformation again.
      setSearchTerm(searchTerm); 
    },
  });
  
  const invalidateQueryOnAction = () => queryClient.invalidateQueries(['google-geocode'])
  
  return { geocodingData, invalidateQueryOnAction }
};
```

**Some component:**

```
const dummyCoords = {
    lat: 33.748997,
    lng: -84.387985
}

const SomeComponent = () => {
  const { geocodingData, invalidateQueryOnAction } =
    useGoogleReverseGeocoding(dummyCoords)

  const handleSomeUserAction = () => {
    // handle action...

    // Invalidate query, so the query gets refetched and onSuccess callback executes again
    invalidateQueryOnAction()
  }
}
```

PS: If `@TkDodo` comes along with a different solution for this, I would suggest to go for it instead.